# Diagonal curtains-like transition between pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make Flutter make special kind of transition between pages, like [here](https://1x8jfe.axshare.com/#g=1&p=splash&c=1) - two elements open up a space like diagonal curtains, there the new page should be.

I can successfully construct the screen, and even make animation. But unfortunately I cannot show the new page under the curtains. There is just an empty space, and once animation is done, the actual transition happens.

[image: Curtain Animation followed by transition]

How can I show the second page before the animation would happened, when the curtains start opening the screen is already there?

[Here is link to the code I use](https://gist.github.com/strokine/9671910ac840a4b143f22ddc2221f218)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/somewhere');` 
You can add Fade-Transition while routing.

Consume following code while navigation -

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
            new PageRouteBuilder(
              pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => new YourWidgetClass(),
              transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) =>
                new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child),
              ) ,
            )
```

Comment: That just takes care of the transition between pages. But the logic still the same - animation opens up the curtains showing empty space -> the other screen fades in.
I'm trying to make the second screen be there already while the curtains are opening.
So, the sequence should be something like this: the first screen is there, second screen appears under it, still not visible, animation kicks in opening the curtains revealing the second screen under.
I'm thinking to use Hero transition into full screen modal on the second page. Will see how it will go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the exact diagonal curtains in the second screen then transition without any animations to second screen, the user won't notice since the rendered view will be identical, and then open the curtains. Voila! your view is already there.

You can find an example here

[Diagonal Curtain example](https://github.com/mertkokusen/flutter_curtain_transition)